# parameterized SQL query in R with in clause

Tags: sql, r, command-line

I want to fetch data from SQL Server in R and the query contains "IN" clause. I have written the query in the below format:

```
res <- fn$sqlQuery(dbhandle, "select * from <tbl> where col1 = '$argv1' and col2 = '$argv2' and col3 in $argv3")
```

and here is how I am passing it from command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" --slave --vanilla "c:\R\abc.R" "A1" "B1"  ("A11","A12")
```

but it removes the parenthesis around A11 and A12 and hence the query at DB end fails.

```
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select * from tbl where col1 = 'A1' and col2 = 'B1' and col3 in (A11,A12) '"
```

Is there an easy way to handle this?

Comment: I have not tested these, but can you try either: `(\"A11\",\"A12\")`  OR `"('A11','A12')"`

Comment: Hi Osssan, 2nd one worked... thanks